# DB Design - Detail table with heterogeneous elements

Tags: database-design

We need to design tables to save action plans. An action plan is a list of actions to achieve a goal.

A basic design would be:
• Plan header table (type, code, dates, author, manager, ...)
• Table with actions to be done

The part that complicates it: the type of plan defines which columns the actions of the plan should have. Each type is a template where we define in a table the columns that must have the action plans that are of this type (column name, data type).

Then, the detail lines have different fields / columns depending on the type indicated in the header. It seems that it cannot be a single table with columns for each line of detail.

This is information to analyze with a BI tool (qliksense) and the data model should be very clear to be able to do so.

How would you design this?

Thanks!!!

FJ

Comment: Since you said the database is for BI analysis, you gave the answer to your question in your question.  A Header table and a Detail table for each and every template.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc You mean dynamically create tables when creating a new template?

Comment: Yes, create a Detail table for every new template,